# Вылетает SimpleCursorAdapter

Tags: java

При создании SimpleCursorAdapter приложение вылетает с

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist
        at android.database.AbstractCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(AbstractCursor.java:333)
        at android.widget.CursorAdapter.init(CursorAdapter.java:180)
        at android.widget.CursorAdapter.<init>(CursorAdapter.java:157)
        at android.widget.ResourceCursorAdapter.<init>(ResourceCursorAdapter.java:96)
        at android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter.<init>(SimpleCursorAdapter.java:104)
        at com.arseniy.schoolhelper.JournalSubjectAdd.onCreateView(JournalSubjectAdd.java:52)
и т.д
```

Место где ошибка (в фрагменте)

```java
//открываем подключение
        databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(getActivity());
        databaseHelper.open();
        //запуск курсора
        cursor = databaseHelper.getAllData();

        String[] headers = new String[] {databaseHelper.COLUMN_SUB};
        int[] to = new int[] {android.R.id.text1};
        // создааем адаптер и настраиваем список
        cursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, cursor, headers, to, 0);
        subjectView.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);
```

И сам код DatabaseHelper

```java
//Работа с БД
public class DatabaseHelper {
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Journal.db"; // название бд
    private static final int VER = 1; // версия базы данных
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "subject"; //название таблицы

    public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_SUB = "SUB";

    protected static final String DB_CREATE =
    "create table " + DATABASE_TABLE + "("
                    + COLUMN_ID + " primary key autoincrement,"
                    + COLUMN_SUB + "text" + ");";

    private final Context ctx;
    private DatabaseHelp dbHelp;
    private SQLiteDatabase SQL;

    public DatabaseHelper(Context ctx) {
        this.ctx = ctx;
    }

    // открыть подключение
    public void open() {
        dbHelp = new DatabaseHelp(ctx, DATABASE_NAME, null, VER);
        SQL = dbHelp.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    // закрыть подключение
    public void close() {
        if (dbHelp != null) dbHelp.close();
    }

    //получить все данные из DATABASE_TABLE
    public Cursor getAllData() {
        return SQL.query(DATABASE_TABLE, null, null, null, null, null, null);
    }

    //добавить запись
    public void addRec(String sub) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(COLUMN_SUB, sub);
        SQL.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);
    }

    //удалить запись
    public void delRec(long id) {
        SQL.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, COLUMN_ID + " = " + id, null);
    }


    //Создание и управление БД
    private class DatabaseHelp extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
        public DatabaseHelp(Context ctx, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
            super(ctx, name, factory, version);
        }

        //создание БД
        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            db.execSQL(DB_CREATE);
        }

        //обновление БД
        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + "subject");
            onCreate(db);
        }
    }
}
```

Где находится ошибка? Уже почти все перепробовал

Comment: вроде все прямо написано, что в БД нет поля '_id'

Comment: оно указано уже

Comment: вы добавили столбец _id позже, после того, как уже запускали приложение для тестов или исправляли его название?

Comment: таблица уже была, я перенес всю работу в отдельный класс, и ничего не переименовывал